# How do I give a Facebook App privileges to post to a Facebook Page (I own both)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

I don't understand something important about permissions and how to grant them. I've made a Facebook page, and I've made an app. I would like the app to be able to post to the page.

Below is my code. I'm using the fb_graph ruby gem, btw (https://github.com/nov/fb_graph)

```
app = FbGraph::Application.new('531508086900000000', :secret => 'd705fda7275125913a10000000000')
token = app.get_access_token
page = FbGraph::Page.new('000000000000000')
note = page.note!( :access_token => token, :subject => 'testing', :message => 'Hey, testing you!')
```

And this is the error:

```
FbGraph::Unauthorized: OAuthException :: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions
```

I've looked everywhere I can think of on both the app and the page settings but can't figure out how to do this. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant access via a user access token. 
The current token in your case is an application access token.

Use one of the methods listed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#adding

Specifically https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#login

Answer (score 0):

I voted up phwd's answer for the help s/he was to me here and in IRC. But it still wasn't really enough information to make sense of why this is so hard. I've decided to post my current working understanding of how this works. These are just my own notes, so I'm sorry in advance for anything unintelligible.

```
So, getting the right access tokens is f***ing hard, and here's my current understanding:

In order to get a token that last forever so that my app can post to a page I have to do this:

1. Create a short-lived user access token with the right scope for the app (manage_pages, publish_actions) using the explorer
    - page access tokens can be obtained via /me/accounts from the explorer page
    - if the user access token that is "live" during the /me/accounts request is short lived then this page access token will be too
    - if it is an extended long-lived token the page access token will have no expiry according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

2. Extend short-lived user access token to a long-lived one via a graph api call, also using exploer (see below)
3. Execute the /me/accounts call to get a page token that doesn't expire

 How to get a long lived user access token
   oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=531------------&client_secret=e005f031ba3d98------------------&fb_exchange_token=CAAHjZA163IbMBAMKSeFTmeV9------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------fonA4P4bPhhdveMLvZBKldEGCB7EvF301wQv1YPrudy5kvI
    where

    client_id          = App Id
    &client_secret     = App Secret
    &fb_exchange_token = short lived user access token via explorer with proper scope

 This gives you the following long lived access token
 access_token=CAAHjZA163Ib---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ehS8g2ZBYU8uZBPmdMay3AAj5tXgAZDZD&expires=5179843

 This is an extended user access_token
 This token can be used to post to the page it was genrated for.
 It can also be used to get a no-expiry page access token when used to issue /me/accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

from [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)  **:**

**Page Access Token**

These access tokens are similar to user access tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page. To obtain a page access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and asking for the manage_pages permission. Once you have the user access token you then [get the page access token via the Graph API.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens)